# What determines if a lizard will increase my maximum stamina?

Tags: shadow-of-the-colossus

Sometimes when I eat a lizard it will increase my stamina, and other times it does not.

What determines whether or not eating  a lizard will increase my stamina?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it has to be a lizard with a shining white tail.
The normal (black) lizards will have no effect on your stamina.

In a similar manner, [eating fruit from trees will increase health](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54569/is-there-any-way-to-increase-my-maximum-health).

Hunting lizards and fruit is a understandably a common pursuit in the game, see [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/924364-shadow-of-the-colossus/faqs/39759) for help if you're looking for it.

The bow is recommended for both pastimes.

Comment: You seem a little uncertain. If you can confirm this I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: I wasn't positive, but I am now.  Been a while since I played!

Comment: This is 100% correct.