# Is there any way to increase my maximum health?

Tags: shadow-of-the-colossus

I've already noticed it's [possible to increase my maximum stamina](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54566/what-determines-if-a-lizard-will-increase-my-stamina), but is it also possible to increase my maximum health, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sure can! You can do so by finding a fruit tree! There are 33 of them in all, and if you find them all, your health bar will span the screen!

Here's a map: [image: Map!]

Map source: http://teamico.wikia.com/wiki/Fruit_trees